# noob level generic collection in java

Tags: java, generics, types, collections

Regarding :

```
List<String> mystring = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Correct me if Im wrong:

`List` is a `Collection`, and could also be `Set`, `Queue` or `Map` also.

`String` is a type.

`mystring` is the name of this variable, and will be a generic collection of `String` objects.

`ArrayList` is a ? and could also be ?

If I'm talking with another developer, what do I call the `ArrayList` thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is an interface.  ArrayList is an implementation of List (as is LinkedList).

Answer (score 1):

1. ArrayList is an implementation of List interface.
2. ArrayList is a concrete class of mystring variable (however in this context it should be insignificant as mystring is of List type)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<String>` is the concrete type of the (badly named) mystring variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. `List` is an interface. An `ArrayList` is a concrete class that implements this interface.
2. A list cannot be a `Set`, `Queue`, `Map`, or anything other than a `List`.
3. `String` is an `Object`.
4. `List<String> mystring = new ArrayList<String>();` implies that `myString` is a collection (in this case, a list) of `String` instances.

Comment: I like this answer it's clear and to the point though I think that you should explain that `Set`, `Queue` and `Map` are themselves interfaces that do not extend from `List`. Also point four I feel requires elaboration to say `mystring` is a (of type) `Collection` because `Collection` is the super interface of `List` in this case it will be a `List` of `String` objects

Answer (score 1):

List is an Interface. It gives the Object a behavior. The ArrayList in this case is the implementation. But it could be also any other object that implements the List Interface. Vector is another example.

In that case, Vector works pretty much like ArrayList however is synchronized. If you need concurrency, you probably are going to use a Vector, but it comes with a price. Its a little slower than ArrayList.

If you ever work in Java Mobile, you'll see that you only have Vector and no ArrayList.

ArrayList could be a collection fo whatever you want, however you are setting the type in your declaration, so its going to expect that type when you retrieve the objects from the list. If you need anything else, you'll have to do casting.

Comment: So [interface]<[type]> [name] = new [implementation of interface]<[type]>();

Comment: Exactly! You are not obligated to use an Interface in the declaration however its best practices to use the first interface that covers your need. For example, if Collection has the methods you require, don't even use List. You could also use ArrayList directly, but in the future, if you need to change your application, it will be harder because you need to update all references.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking to another developer about this specific line of code, and your topic of discussion is concerning an ordered collection of elements, you should probably call it a List. That way, you can access all the List specific behavior characterized by the  mystring object.

You can interact with it as you would any collection (i.e. List, Queue, Set). Then you can only access the common denominator behavior among all those types. By the way, a Collecton or more specifically a List cannot be a Map.